# How do you let the arrow keys move your focus around in WinForms TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

It seems that the default is the up and left keys go to the previous tabstop, and the down/right keys go to the next tabstop.  I've got a TableLayoutPanel each with one button in it.  Is there an easy way to make the arrow keys focus the button in the cell to the corresponding direction in the TableLayoutPanel instead of just following the tabstops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  Just create your own TableLayoutPanel override and have it process the cursor keys to get what you want.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new panel from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the old one.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyLayoutPanel : TableLayoutPanel {
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        var ctl = this.FindForm().ActiveControl;
        if (ctl.Parent == this) {
            int col = this.GetColumn(ctl);
            int row = this.GetRow(ctl);
            if (keyData == Keys.Left && col > 0) {
                var newctl = this.GetControlFromPosition(col - 1, row);
                if (newctl != null) newctl.Focus();
                return true;
            }
            // etc..
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice.  I am sorry I did not realize the nature of the problem in my (deleted now) answer.